# Call same javascript twice in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making an advertising system and using javascript to push my media on websites pages. But i got a problem, when i write my code many times in my page :

```
<script charset="ISO-8859-1" type="text/javascript" src="http://wads/get/1/728x90.adv"></script>
```

My browser only makes one call, how can i do to avoid the cache system (if the problem is cache) ? I already add a max-age=0 in my header.

I am using rails 3.1 and jQuery.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just output a rails datatimestamp as a query string to your src:

```
example in PHP would be: "http://wads/get/1/728x90.adv?<?php echo time(); ?>"
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but it's too hard to explain that to customers. I want something simple for them.